# Trying to Combine Multiple Instances of an Item in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I'm in the process of making a simple text-based survival game in Java as my final project. I'm still stuck with creating the inventory. Today, I got it working somewhat (adding and removing items properly), but when a third different kind of item was added, it overwrote the second. I no longer have this code and my teacher helped "fix it" and now it doesn't even display the inventory.

Main Class:

```
public class SurvivalGame{

//inv
  static ArrayList<Item> inv = new ArrayList<Item>();
//items
  static Item Water = new Item("Water ", 1);

public static void main(String[] args){
//intro();
addItem(Water);
addItem(Water);
removeItem(Water);
showInv();
}
```

Add Item Method:

```
public static void addItem(Item item){
for(int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++){
  if(inv.get(i).getName().equals(item.getName())){
    inv.get(i).addQuantity();
  }
break;
  }
System.out.println("Item added: 1 " + item.getName());}
```

Remove Item Method:

```
public static void removeItem(Item item){
for(int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++){
  if((inv.get(i).getName()).equals(item.getName())){
    if((inv.get(i).getQuantity()) == 0){
      inv.remove(item);
    }
    else inv.get(i).minusQuantity();
  }
  break;
}

System.out.println("Item removed: 1 " + item.getName());}
```

Show Inventory Method:

```
public static void showInv(){
System.out.println("You have the following: ");
for(int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++)
  inv.get(i).showItem();
  }
}//(end of class)
```

Item Class:

```
public class Item{

String name;
int quantity;

public Item(String n, int q){
  name = n;
  quantity = q;
}

public String getName(){
  return name;}

public void addQuantity(){
  quantity += 1;}

public void minusQuantity(){
  quantity -= 1;}

public int getQuantity(){
  return quantity;}

public void showItem(){
  System.out.println(getQuantity() + " " + getName());}

}//(end of class)
```

It's probably something small that I'm overlooking, so some help would be really appreciated! I can't be more of a beginner at this, and I've already tried rewriting this several times. I have no idea how to use lists so I would prefer to leave the inventory as an ArrayList. I considered making each instance of each Item take up its own "inventory slot" but that's not good enough for me. Lastly, I did not include the Player class as it is irrelevant here. It doesn't touch the inventory or the Items, etc.

The System prints the adding and removal messages, but does not print the contents of the inventory, as it had up to two items before.

Comment: Stepping through with a debugger should pretty quickly uncover what line isn't being called when you think it is or what value is not updated as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two obvious points in your `addItem` method:

```
public static void addItem(Item item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++) {
        if (inv.get(i).getName().equals(item.getName())) {
            inv.get(i).addQuantity();
        }
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Item added: 1 " + item.getName());
}
```

First: The `break;` should be within the body of your `if`, because now it will exit the loop after the first run every time.

Second: You're missing the initial add when you don't have that item in your inventory yet. You're only increasing the quantity for existing items.

Try this:

```
public static void addItem(Item item) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++) {
        if (inv.get(i).getName().equals(item.getName())) {
            inv.get(i).addQuantity();
            // Remember that we already had the item in inventory
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        // Item isn't in inventory yet: add it
        inv.add(item);
    }
    System.out.println("Item added: 1 " + item.getName());
}
```

Note that your `removeItem` method also looks strange:

```
public static void removeItem(Item item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++) {
        if ((inv.get(i).getName()).equals(item.getName())) {
            if ((inv.get(i).getQuantity()) == 0) {
                inv.remove(item);
            }
            else inv.get(i).minusQuantity();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` again should be inside your (first) `if` and you want to call `minusQuantity()` in any case.

Consider an item with quantity 1 in your inventory: Your first condition yields `false`, because `getQuantity()` is not 0, so you're calling `minusQuantity()` and end up with an item of quantity 0 still in your inventory.

Try this:

```
public static void removeItem(Item item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inv.size(); i++) {
        if (inv.get(i).getName().equals(item.getName())) {
            // Reduce quantity
            inv.get(i).minusQuantity();
            if (inv.get(i).getQuantity() == 0) {
                // We don't have any quantity left: remove item from inventory
                inv.remove(item);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to come back and say that I forgot to do "else, inv.add(item);

Comment: Wow, thank you so very much!!! It works perfectly now, even with two or more items. I understand completely why and how it works (I never use stuff that "works" but I do not know why or how).